# Qual função permite abrir arquivo .txt e rodar outras funções no conteudo deste .txt?

Tags: c, arquivo, txt, file-get-contents

Qual função em linguagem C permite abrir arquivo `.txt` e rodar outras funções no conteúdo deste `.txt`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Em essência é o [`fopen()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) que abre e depois tem um [conjunto de funções que são usadas para manipular os dados e acesso ao conteúdo do arquivo e finalmente fechar o arquivo](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io). Mas tem uma enormidade de formas de acessar arquivos que podem atender necessidades diferentes dessa, a maioria de APIs específicas de sistemas operacionais. Exemplo básico:

```
// Abre o arquivo em modo de escrita estendida (leitura/gravação)
// e retorna um ponteiro para um file stream (fluxo de arquivo).
FILE *file = fopen("arquivo.txt", "w+");
char str[101];
// Lê 101 bytes do arquivo texto e joga na variável str.
fscanf(file, "%s", str);
// Exibe em tela o conteúdo lido do arquivo texto.
printf("|%s|\n", str);
// Fecha o arquivo texto.
fclose(file);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/IO/HandlingFile.c).

Não tem nada pronto que abre, carrega todo o conteúdo e disponibiliza. C não tem essa filosofia de "pilhas inclusas", você tem que fazer tudo o que deseja além do básico e se souber fazer de forma genérica poderá usar esta função em todas suas aplicações.